# Linux mail command treating -b and -c as email addresses

Tags: linux, postfix

I am trying to send an email from a linux machine using the mail command which is as follows:

```
echo "Test content" | mail -s Test email1@address.com -b email2@address.com -c email3@address.com
```

It sends the email but also treats "-b" and "-c" as email addresses. So, in the email, I can see

> "-b@domain.name" and "-c@domain.name"

.

Can someone help me on how I can exclude "-b" and "-c" from the recipients list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify all of the switches before the final recipient. This should work:

```
echo "Test content" | mail -s Test -b email2@address.com -c email3@address.com email1@address.com
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)